# llround, but for unsigned long as target type?

Tags: c, rounding

Does a function like `llround` exist which returns an unsigned long? It's especially important also to handle "edge"-cases with input double-values which are outside of the `unsigned long` range.

Unfortunately, I could not find this.

Thanks

Comment: Which behavior would you expect outside the `unsigned long` range? (for `llround()` the behavior is unspecified outside the return type range).

Comment: Ah okay, I though `llround` will return the min and max value of `long`. That would be my preferred behavior.

Comment: @nielson: The behavior is not unspecified. Although C 2018 7.12.9.7, about `llround`, says the numeric result is unspecified and a domain error or range error “may” occur, 7.12.1 is more specific. Paragraph 4 says a *range error* occurs if and only if the mathematical result of the function cannot be represented in an object of the specified type, due to extreme magnitude,” which leaves no option. Paragraph 2 says “a *domain* error occurs if and only if an input argument is outside the domain over which the mathematical function is defined”, which I think applies to infinities and NaNs…

Comment: @EricPostpischil This is a play of words. In my understanding "behavior" includes the numeric result.

Comment: … (For any finite argument, the mathematical function of rounding to an integer is defined, even if it will not fit into the destination, so those are not domain errors. Whereas for an infinity or NaN, the mathematical function of rounding to an integer is not defined.) Also paragraph 2 says an implementation-defined value is returned, although paragraph 4 omits this.

Comment: @nielsen: There is a specification of the behavior. Therefore the behavior is not unspecified. This is simple logic, not wordplay. OP specifically asked for handling of range errors, so the specification of behavior for range errors is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Any integer type will eventually by too small for any `double` value.

But if you want to write a simple function:

```
unsigned long long llround(const double x)
{
    return x > 0.0 ? (unsigned long long)(x + 0.5) : 0;
}


int main(void)
{
    for (double x = 10.0; x <= 11.0; x += 0.05)
    {
        printf("%f - %llu\n", x, llround(x));
    }
}
```

Comment: If the upperbound is also checked in the function, it looks already quite good. I'm not yet too sure if it always rounds to the nearest unsigned long value. For sure this works for small numbers, but for large numbers the gaps between numbers might become large.

Comment: This gets the wrong answer for `x` = ½−2^−54, using IEEE-754 binary64. Then `x` is 0.499999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375, and the result should be 0, but `x + .5` rounds to 1, so the routine returns 1. It also gets wrong answers for odd numbers in [2^52, 2^53). In that interval, adding ½ to `x` has a real-number-arithmetic result midway between two representable values, so the computed result is rounded to the even choice, so the routine returns `x+1` when it should return `x`.